# Spring project deploy on real server

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC project running locally on tomcat right now. What I need to do to be able to run it on my linux server? How can I deploy it? Before I used firezilla(running usual jars) to connect to server using ssh. Please help me by writing easy steps on how to run web application on server, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of answers to this just have to google (i found about 10 in first couple pages that were good).

It all varies based on your environment, build setup etc.

Here is example of deploying with maven to tomcat

http://www.mkyong.com/maven/how-to-deploy-maven-based-war-file-to-tomcat/

and another

http://bitbybitblog.com/deploy-to-tomcat/

Some IDEs also have inbuilt functions that take care of this for you as well.